# Ropsten issues - two forks happening, transactions showing in both places

Tags: ropsten, forks

There seems to be a few issues going on with ropsten right now:

https://twitter.com/sbetamc/status/1092167042709573633
https://twitter.com/stevenleeg/status/1092546643604459521

At the same time, a node that I have running seems to be running on a different chain when compared to ropsten.etherscan.io.

I'm on block 4959146, while etherscan is on 4958946 (and some previous blocks also don't match

Additionally, it seems that transactions are somehow reaching both forks. The transaction `0xb7ac2d4109d1c69b8b874bc71e4c6b09c94240973548584dcee581ff57e07bed` shows up on both etherscan and my own node, but in non-matching blocks.

So, two questions really:

1. what's up with ropsten right now?
2. will it be solved on its own (via a rollback, or something), or do I need to resync my node?